# pages are not refreshing in phonegap android app

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building an app using phonegap and jquery-mobile.

Everything is working fine when i visit the pages for first time.

But when visit the pages 2nd time, the changes which all i have made in the first time retains..

suppose if I have altered the position of image to `X=1 and Y=10` in the first time and when i visit 2nd time, the `X and Y` values remains same.

How do i refresh the pages when i visit after the first time?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Mobile's `pagebeforeshow` event, which triggers when you navigate to a target page. Then in the event handler you can reset your variables.

For example:

```
$('#mypage').on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    // Reset your page here
});
```

Comment: right now i am using the same thing         $(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#mypage',function() {
});

Comment: Can't you reset your values in the function? It's not the same as refreshing, but it gives the same result.